# Counterexample to the observable algebra of a region and its causal completion being the same

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime, causality, observables, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I was reading a paper by Ed Witten called "Algebras, Regions and Observers". It can be found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.02837

A major theme is theorems relating the algebra of observables for a spacetime region to a larger one. In section 3.3, it is claimed that the best one could hope for is the additive algebra corresponding to a region $U$ being the same as the algebra of its causal completion.

A counterexample to this claim is then given. Assume a theory where there only exists a massless scalar field. Then its correlation function for an even spacetime dimension is supported on the light cone (because it's massless). So the algebras regions outside the light cone of $U$ commute with the algebra of $U$, therefore it can not be contained in it. At least that's what I think the argument is. Now, if $U$ is NOT connected, and is such that it contains points both at the future and the past of a region $O$, but such that it is not reachable from $O$ with a null geodesic, its causal completion contains $O$. This means that the algebra of $O$ is contained in that of the causal completion of $U$. But before we found that it can't be contained in the algebra of $U$, so it can't possibly be that $U$ and its causal completion have the same algebra.

This is the overall argument as I understand it. However, what I don't understand is why $U$ can't be connected. In particular, why does it have to have points both at the future and the past of $O$? Take $O$ to be a little ball in 2D spacetime around the origin. The set of all null geodesics passing through $O$ is kind of like a thickened X around the origin. Chose $U$ to be some other ball right below $O$ (on the t axis), small enough so that it doesn't intersect the thickened X. Then if I understand things right, its causal completion contains $O$, while not being reachable from $O$ with a null geodesic, but again the same argument should apply. What's wrong with my thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ι actually figured out my mistake. This is not a counterexample because the causal completion of the set in my "counterexample", being the causal complement of the causal complement (the causal complement of a set being all the points that are spacelike separated to it) actually can not contain the ball $O$. I got confused because I misunderstood the causal completion. In fact you can show that in 2D spacetime, the causal completion of a ball is basically just a square that circumscribes it and this contains no points that can not be reached via a light ray from inside the ball (as every 45 degree line within the square intersects the ball). I'm pretty sure it's a theorem you can't achieve a counterexample in Minkowski spacetime with a simply connected set, but I haven't proved it yet.